# Xamarin.Forms Simple basepage OnAppearing() no suitable method found

Tags: c#, oop, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have this very simple basepage which inherits the ContentPage class:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace C4SL.LEAP.Mobile.Code.Views
{
    public abstract class LEAPPage : ContentPage
    {
        public String Breadcrumb { get; set; }
        public LEAPPage()
        {
            this.Breadcrumb = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i inherit my view class from LEAPPage instead of ContentPage, i'm experiencing some weird trouble when overriding the OnAppearing() method stating that 'no suitable method found to override'.. I must be missing something very easy here.. can someone help me out?

My view class looks as follows:

```
using Plugin.Connectivity;
using Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions;
using C4SL.LEAP.Mobile.Code.Views;

namespace C4SL.LEAP.Mobile.Fundamentals
{
    public partial class Main : LEAPPage
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged +=         Current_ConnectivityChanged;
        }

        private void Current_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution myself:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27265/contentpage-inherit-from-custom-basepage

The problem was that my viewclass was partial and i had to add a reference in the XAML file.